I can't install the Spacy library using the terminal in VSCode on Windows 10
I am trying to install the Spacy library in VSCode in a folder with a virtual environment. The output appearing in the terminal is excessively long; I will share it with a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/xK9UYbEy) later. My version of Python is Python 3.13.0 and pip is pip 2.42, so they are up to date.
I think the most important part is the following:
× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [113 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version < "3.9"' don't match your environment

[74 lines of output]
        Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version < "3.9"' don't match your environment

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

In the spacy GitHub repository, they provide a possible explanation. They say it may be necessary to install a previous version of Python, but if this were true, many people would have this problem. I’m not sure.
I have followed the instructions from the official Visual Studio Code website for Python and Spacy as well. I have installed vs_buildsTools to have a C++ compiler too, But I cannot continue, i have always the same issue.
